# Why is my CSS Sticky Header working intermittently

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have implemented a CSS-based sticky header using CSS like

```
nav {
    position: sticky; top: 0;
}
```

I implemented it just find this page in edcint.co.nz/public/data/scenery (copy and paste this link otherwise it will load a blank page)

But in a related page, that uses a lot of the same code and css (same lazy loading and infinite scroll), the header seems to come and go as you scroll down the page. Once you reach the bottom of page (lazy loading and infinite scroll are in play here - but same as on the page that works ok), then the header works ok.
[Intermittent Page Sample](https://www.edcint.co.nz/cgi-bin/webalbum_search.cgi?searchterms=.&mode=search&searchfile=.webalbum_search_data_public.conf_2&albumtophtmldir=%2Fpublic%2Fdata%2F&resultnumber=0&linkback=%2Fpublic%2Fdata%2Findex.shtml&modtime=0&shortform=n&submit=&approxsearch=1&showimages=1&showvideos=1&showfolders=1&showwithcomments=1&showwithnocomments=1&imageheight=200&displayimageinfo=1&maxresults=10&modtimedays=0&ssdelay=15)

I can't work out why it does not work. None of the parent items have overflow set etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It works but its z-index is small so you should increase it :

```
nav {
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work and it still doesn't work when adding z-index:100 (now on the test pages)

Comment: So you should a big number because some part of your DOM has a bigger z-index than your sticky nav; try for example 999

Comment: No sorry. I set it to 9999 and the behaviour is still the same. The header intermittently appears and disappears as I scroll down the page

Comment: It's only because of priority of z-index; Try this case that wrap all your other DOM expect your sticky menu in a div and add `position: relative;`and `z-index:1` maybe it solve the issue

Comment: Sorry, it still does not work. I made .controls `z-index:9999` and `<resultsdisplay>` (which is the scrolling part) `z-index:1`

Comment: I'm not really sure how this can be a z-index issue since it intermittently works which would imply that the z-index is constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are floating the single results:

```
.single_result {
    float: left;
}
```

You are better off removing that attribute and setting the results container to grid or flex so that the layout of these elements is determined there and the elements are not taken out of general flow of the page.

```
.results {
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 300px));
}
```

Comment: This does make a difference. Changing as suggested does keep the header sticky. Now I just have to work out how to resolve the formatting issues that it presents